# How to let plugin access file in resource folder of any project where it runs

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-15

I have created a plugin. It needs to access 2 files from res folder. Now the trick here is, res folder is not inside plugin. For example, i have published plugin locally, so it now visible under any project you create, inside Tools Menu. What i want is, any new project i create, it will have 2 files facility.json & groups.json inside res folder, now my plugin should be able to access these files. I have tried different approach like as shown below, but it always fails, saying "File not found" exception. If anyone can help me out in this. Its appreciated. Thank you.

```
private static File getFileFromResource(String fileName) throws URISyntaxException {

    ClassLoader classLoader = Validator.class.getClassLoader();
    URL resource = classLoader.getResource(fileName);
    if (resource == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("file not found! " + fileName);
    } else {

        // failed if files have whitespaces or special characters
        //return new File(resource.getFile());

        return new File(resource.toURI());
    }

}

private static InputStream getFileFromResourceAsStream(String fileName) {

    // The class loader that loaded the class
    ClassLoader classLoader = Validator.class.getClassLoader();
    InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName);

    // the stream holding the file content
    if (inputStream == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("file not found! " + fileName);
    } else {
        return inputStream;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the neat part, you don't.
you have to add them by yourself each time you make a new project since res folder isn't a plugin, instead res is for resource (assuming you use res as resource)

Try this by manually add each facility.json & groups.json with

```
InputStream IS = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/file name");
```

or

```
InputStream IS = getClass().getResourceAsStream("root/dir/file name");
```

your plugin already published locally so maybe adding address might be help

if still not, try to save your clean project that only have facility.json & groups.json inside res folder as your project template. it depends on your IDE,

Intelij IDEA -Jetbrain : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/saving-project-as-template.html

NetBeans IDE -Apache : https://netbeans.apache.org/tutorials/nbm-filetemplates.html

as my experience, im creating my own netbeans template for new project

Comment: hey, this solution dosent help. I have tried them. Thanks for your time.